# How can I get all filenames which are uploaded via file dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started with learning React JS and my problem is that; I want to select multiple file from file dialog and then I want to display them on the screen with their name.

```
<RaisedButton className="raisedBtn" label="Video Ekle" onClick={this.openFileDialog}>
           <input
             ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
             style={{"display" : "none"}}
             type="file" multiple   
             onChange={this.handleFileChange}
             >
           </input>
         </RaisedButton>
```

There is okay.

`openFileDialog(){
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.textInput).click();
  }`

There is okay again.

The problem is there:

```
handleFileChange(e){
var files = e.target.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  var fileName = file.name;

  reader.onload = (e) => {
      tilesData.push({img: e.target.result, title: fileName})
      this.setState({image: e.target.result,  title: fileName});

 };

reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   }
}
```

All images name are the same **(all of them have the last selected file's name)**. I think reader.onload is running asynchronous so the for loop go on but reader.onload is not finish the running? How can I fix it?

Thanks in your advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: it's related to very interesting topic of js "Closures", use `let` instead of `var` here, it should work: `let fileName = file.name;` Check the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable) for diff between these two.

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks it works. 
"The difference is scoping. var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, which can be smaller than a function block. Both are global if outside any block.

Also, variables declared with let are not accessible before they are declared in their enclosing block"